# Make django display non-jinja element while waiting for it to be completed

Tags: python, django, frontend, jinja2, backend

So here's what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have a really long function that takes some time to process. Eventually, the output needs to be displayed on a webpage.

I'm using Python 3.6 and Django 2 framework.

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import time

def f():
    time.sleep(5)
    return [5,6,7]

def index(request):
    return render(request,'homepage/page.html', {'funcF':f})
```

So as you can see, I have a function that waits for 5 seconds to pass before returning an array of numbers.

***homepage/page.html***

```
<p> Hello there! </p>

{% for r in funcF %}
<p> {{r}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

My goal is that I want *Hello there!* to be displayed and wait for 5 seconds to pass, then display the numbers in the array.

In it's current state, the webpage instead takes 5 seconds to reload, and it displays both *Hello there!* and the numbers on the array all at once.

Any bright ideas?

Comment: Load the main page via django, fetch the output of `f()` via an ajax call.  The page can show a spinner while waiting.

Comment: Can you explain how I could link the python function with javascript?

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144768/javascript-ajax-call-on-page-onload

Comment: The answer you've provided didn't use any python related functions. I'm not sure how I to apply my Python function to the provided AJAX code.

Answer (score 0):

Ill be operating under the assumption that your call to time.sleep(5) is just to show/simulate a function that takes 5 seconds to compute. So operating under that assumption one way would be to break it into two endpoints, the later being a rest endpoint, so the web browser requests the hello world page, you return just the page, but you also add a little javascript to the page that makes an ajax get request to your rest endpoint with the function that takes a bit to run, the user shouldn't notice anything different while this is happening and when the function finishes and returns the array you can use your javascript to build the

elements.