# Ajax not firing untill page reload - PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap

I am building a phonegap application and I have integrated ajax functionality within it.

Firstly I would like to say that there is no issue with CORS or whitelisting, the AJAX call actually works but it doesn't seem to activate on page load.

HTML:

```
<div id="ajax-loader" style="background-image: url(images/loader.gif);background-position: top center;background-repeat: no-repeat;position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:50px; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:140px 0 50px 0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

JS:

```
  $.get("https://www.example.com/getPage.php?page=disclaimer",function(data){
         $("#info").append(data);
    }).done(function() {
         $('#ajax-loader').css('display','none');
  });
```

Like the title says, once I access the page, I see the preloader as expected but from the console I don't see any AJAX activities, once I refresh the page on the other hand then everything fires as normal.

I have tried putting the code inside the DeviceReady state and various other states, but seems to be the same. Any suggestions on fixing this so the AJAX fires once I access the page?

EDIT: Initially I implemented an iFrame solution which worked in the same way, preloader shows whilst page is loading in the background then it disappears when the page is ready. The iFrame took around 4-7 seconds for a lot of plaintext so I decided to use AJAX which only takes about 1-2 seconds.

FULL BODY:

```
<body class="theme-light" data-highlight="blue2">    
<div id="page">

    <div id="page-preloader">
        <div class="loader-main"><div class="preload-spinner border-highlight"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="header header-fixed header-logo-app">
        <a href="pages.html" class="back-button header-title">Back to pages</a>
        <a href="pages.html" class="header-icon header-icon-1 back-button"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="header-icon header-icon-2" data-toggle-theme><i class="fa fa-moon"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-menu footer-5-icons footer-menu-center-icon">
        <a href="book.html" ><i class="fa fa-car"></i><span>Book</span></a>
        <a href="dashboard.html" ><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
        <a href="main.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Home</span></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>   


    <div class="page-content header-clear">   

        <div class="page-title has-subtitle">
            <div class="page-title-left">
                <a href="#" class="font-24">Disclaimer</a>
                <span class="color-highlight">Information</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="ajax-loader" style="background-image: url(images/loader.gif);background-position: top center;background-repeat: no-repeat;position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:50px; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:140px 0 50px 0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="menu-hider"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js" async></script>
<script>

  $.get("https://www.example.com/getPage.php?page=disclaimer",function(data){
         $("#info").append(data);
    }).done(function() {
         $('#ajax-loader').css('display','none');
  });

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144768/javascript-ajax-call-on-page-onload/4144801#4144801

Comment: tried ready state already didn't work thanks

Comment: @Enoch Can you share the full snippet to see from where the ajax call has been triggered?

Comment: @VishnuSKrish edited

Comment: Your code should work inside `deviceready` event. Have you tried that? Did you debug the app with Chrome Dev Tools?